# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'material'

Tags: django, module, django-runserver

python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1052, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 989, in run
self._target(*self.*args, **self.*kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ROG\OneDrive\Bureau\iblogs\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper

fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ROG\OneDrive\Bureau\iblogs\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\Users\ROG\OneDrive\Bureau\iblogs\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
raise *exception[1]
File "C:\Users\ROG\OneDrive\Bureau\iblogs\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init**.py", line 394, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "C:\Users\ROG\OneDrive\Bureau\iblogs\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper

fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ROG\OneDrive\Bureau\iblogs\venv\Lib\site-packages\django_*init**.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\ROG\OneDrive\Bureau\iblogs\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate

app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ROG\OneDrive\Bureau\iblogs\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create

import_module(entry)
File "C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 90, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
p>", line 1318, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'material'

nothing ?!!!
nothing ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add 'material' to your project folder settings.py/INSTALLED_APPS